# Clone snapshot of hbase table from one namespace into another namespace

Tags: hadoop, hbase

I am using Hbase version 0.98. When I try to clone the hbase table present in namespace "sample1" using snapshot, it is failing.

```
hbase(main):003:0> snapshot 'sample1:deliverytable_m1' 'deliverytable_m1-Snapshot'

ERROR: wrong number of arguments (1 for 2)

Here is some help for this command:
Take a snapshot of specified table. Examples:

  hbase> snapshot 'sourceTable', 'snapshotName'
  hbase> snapshot 'namespace:sourceTable', 'snapshotName', {SKIP_FLUSH => true}
```

I want to clone the snapshot into another namespace "sample2" as below. I want 'deliverytable_m2' to be cloned in 'sample2' namespace. How to do it?

```
clone_snapshot 'deliverytable_m1-Snapshot' 'sample2:deliverytable_m2'
```

Comment: Are you sure that the table is in sample1 namespace? I hope you have checked with **list_namespace_tables 'sample1'**. if it is a default namespace, you need not mention it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first error you got is simply because you forgot the comma between your arguments. It should look like this:

```
hbase(main):039:0> snapshot 'sample1:deliverytable_m1', 'deliverytable_m1-Snapshot'
```

At this point, you should have a snapshot, which you can verify with:

```
hbase(main):044:0> list_snapshots
SNAPSHOT                                                 TABLE + CREATION TIME
 deliverytable_m1-Snapshot                               sample1:deliverytable_m1 (Thu Sep 17 15:17:31 -0600 2015)
1 row(s) in 0.0110 seconds

=> ["deliverytable_m1-Snapshot"]
```

Then, assuming the namespace exists, you can clone the snapshot:

```
hbase(main):045:0> clone_snapshot 'deliverytable_m1-Snapshot', 'sample2:deliverytable_m1'
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that the table is in sample1 namespace? I hope you have checked with **list_namespace_tables 'sample1'**. if it is a default namespace, you need not mention it

Comment: Yes the table is in namespace. Here is my query.hbase(main):003:0> list_namespace_tables 'sample1'
TABLE
deliverytable_m1
1 row(s) in 0.0190 seconds

Comment: ok so now that the table and namespace are there, did you try without namespace. Just to chek if the namespace is the issue here.

Comment: Yes I tried. I get the same result. hbase(main):001:0> snapshot 'deliverytable_m1' 'deliverytable_m1-Snapshot'

ERROR: wrong number of arguments (1 for 2)

Here is some help for this command:
Take a snapshot of specified table. Examples:

  hbase> snapshot 'sourceTable', 'snapshotName'
  hbase> snapshot 'namespace:sourceTable', 'snapshotName', {SKIP_FLUSH => true}

Comment: So issue is with basic snapshot command. Can you confirm this **that snapshot support is turned on by checking if the hbase.snapshot.enabled property in hbase-site.xml is set to true.**

Comment: Snapshot property is not set in hbase-site.xml. It is not working for namespace, but when the source table is in default namespace, the table is created successfully.                                      snapshot 'deliverytable_m1', 'deliverytable_m1-Snapshot'
clone_snapshot 'deliverytable_m1-Snapshot', 'deliverytable_m2'

Comment: ok so even after property is set, the namespace is not working, but it is working for default namespace. So even though we did not find solution, we identified the issue. Good learning. Thank you. Please post if you identified the solution, about why non-default namespace is not working